# describing a child's footsteps on stairs

Tags: creative-writing, word-choice

I am trying to write a scene where dad is trying to get house ready for his mother visiting, so he has got up early to tidy and sweep stuff under the sofa (not literally lol) His daughter has woken up she is excited Grandma is coming, how best do I describe her running down the stairs? Just like that or would you add a "sound"  ie.

I heard the patter of her feet running down stairs? Or is there a better word that I am missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How old is she?

Comment: How important is this part of the story?

Comment: she is 4 and it is a minor part however it is the first paragraph of the book

Answer (score 0):

*"Someone is knocking at the door !, that's too early for Mom to come, who is it ?"* I anxiously wondered.

*"Dad, when is grandma coming ?!"* Turns out it's my son coming down the stairs.